# No value associated with key CodingKeys with Unsplash API

Tags: json, swift, codable

Im trying to decode this json from the Unsplash API, but the ContentView is coming up as blank, and if I print the results then I am getting the "No value associated with key CodingKeys" error. Its strange, because I'm following this very new tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmOe9vNopjU. I am very puzzled, because this should be simple, but I am new to Swift.

here is the full error

```
"No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"total\", intValue: nil) (\"total\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

here is the decoding request

```
class SearchObjectController : ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SearchObjectController()
    private init() {}
    
    var token = "my client id"
    @Published var results = [Result]()
    @Published var searchText : String = "Forest"
    
    func search () {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=\(searchText)")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Client-ID\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            
            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
                self.results.append(contentsOf: res.results)
                print(self.results)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

and these are the Structs i created for that request

```
struct Results : Codable {
    var total : Int
    var results : [Result]
}

struct Result : Codable {
    var id : String
    var description : String?
    var urls : URLs
}

struct URLs : Codable {
    var small : String
}
```

the json format for Unplash API Requests looks like this

```
{
  "total": 133,
  "total_pages": 7,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "eOLpJytrbsQ",
      "created_at": "2014-11-18T14:35:36-05:00",
      "width": 4000,
      "height": 3000,
      "color": "#A7A2A1",
      "blur_hash": "LaLXMa9Fx[D%~q%MtQM|kDRjtRIU",
      "likes": 286,
      "liked_by_user": false,
      "description": "A man drinking a coffee.",
      "user": {
        "id": "Ul0QVz12Goo",
        "username": "ugmonk",
        "name": "Jeff Sheldon",
        "first_name": "Jeff",
        "last_name": "Sheldon",
        "instagram_username": "instantgrammer",
        "twitter_username": "ugmonk",
        "portfolio_url": "http://ugmonk.com/",
        "profile_image": {
          "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1441298803695-accd94000cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=32&w=32&s=7cfe3b93750cb0c93e2f7caec08b5a41",
          "medium": "https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1441298803695-accd94000cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=64&w=64&s=5a9dc749c43ce5bd60870b129a40902f",
          "large": "https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1441298803695-accd94000cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=128&w=128&s=32085a077889586df88bfbe406692202"
        },
        "links": {
          "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/ugmonk",
          "html": "http://unsplash.com/@ugmonk",
          "photos": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/ugmonk/photos",
          "likes": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/ugmonk/likes"
        }
      },
      "current_user_collections": [],
      "urls": {
        "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f",
        "full": "https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f",
        "regular": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&s=92f3e02f63678acc8416d044e189f515",
        "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=263af33585f9d32af39d165b000845eb",
        "thumb": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&s=8aae34cf35df31a592f0bef16e6342ef"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/eOLpJytrbsQ",
        "html": "http://unsplash.com/photos/eOLpJytrbsQ",
        "download": "http://unsplash.com/photos/eOLpJytrbsQ/download"
      }
    },
    // more photos ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: First check if you got an error, then check the response: `if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse { ... }`, then check the status code

Comment: Ive updated my question to show the full error. It suggests that total is missing, but if I remove total, the error changes to "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"results\", intValue: nil) (\"results\").", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: You probably got an error and not the response you expected. So, check for server errors

Comment: Your answer isnt very clear. could you at least expand beyond checking for server errors. I checked the response using the code if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse { ... } you gave me and it printed the same error but with totals. I'm still in the same position as I was

Comment: Right after the `guard let data` line print the received string: `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)`. I'm sure it reveals an error in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you! yes that printed out OAuth error: {"errors":["OAuth error: The access token is invalid"]}.It would suggest that token im using is wrong? but I am copying the Access Key from the Unsplash API straight into the token variable

Comment: @SpikeThea, that would be a different issue then - so, should be a different question. But like I said - perhaps not very clearly - you got a server error and the JSON was not the response you expected to decode, hence the decoding error you're seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common practice for a lot of APIs to return a detailed description of the error in the response body together with the error code when the request can't be processed. Seems that it's your case since the JSON parsing fails on the first field of the structure. Check the `error` and `response.statusCode` in the dataTask's `completion` block first to be sure that the API has successfully processed your request and returned valid data.

Comment: The `DecodingError` clearly indicates that valid JSON is received, however obviously  not the expected JSON. If an error occurs in the completion block then `data` is `nil` and it doesn't reach the decoding line. And if a server error occurs the server sends HTML and you get an `Unexpected character at index 0` error.

Answer (score 0):

It was a missing a space between Client-ID and (token) that was causing the error.